# How to collect all the results

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have the following program:

```
ingrediente(X):-
        member(X,
                [
                    "almendra"
                    , "arroz"
                    , "atun"
                ]
            )
        .


tortitas(X):-
        ingrediente(Y)
        ,atom_concat("Tortitas de ", Y,X)
        .

ensalada(X):-
        ingrediente(Y)
        ,atom_concat("Ensalada de ", Y,X)
        .

ensalada(X):-
        ingrediente(Y)
        ,ingrediente(Z)
        , Y \= Z
        ,atom_concat(" Con ", Z, ConZ)
        ,atom_concat(Y, ConZ, YConz)
        ,atom_concat("Ensalada de ", YConz,X)
        ,!
        .

sopa(X):-
        ingrediente(Y)
        ,atom_concat("Sopa de ", Y,X)
        .

platillo(X):-
        sopa(X).

platillo(X):-
        ensalada(X).

platillo(X):-
        tortitas(X).

write_menu:-
    open('output.txt',write,Out)
    , maplist(platillo, Platillos)
    , forall(member(Platillo,Platillos), write(Out,Platillo))
    , close(Out)
    .
```

It creates the file for me, but does not write the results. How can I correct the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace the code, you'll find that `Platillos` is the empty list, so the `forall` does nothing. You can see this by doing the query:

```
?- maplist(platillo, Platillos).
Platillos = [] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra'] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra'] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra'] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra'] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra'] ;
Platillos = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de almendra']
```

Instead of `maplist`, try `bagof` (or `setof`):

```
?- bagof(X, platillo(X), Xs).
Xs = ['Sopa de almendra', 'Sopa de arroz', 'Sopa de atun', 'Ensalada de almendra', 'Ensalada de arroz', 'Ensalada de atun', 'Ensalada de almendra Con arroz', 'Tortitas de almendra', 'Tortitas de arroz'|...].
```

Comment: For printing, you can use `maplist` on the list you get from the `bagof`. Or you can do `forall(platillo(X), writeln(X))`: `bagof(X, platillo(X), Xs), maplist(writeln, Xs).`